# Using Trello API Key in a Django Project

Tags: python, django, api, trello

I've checked Stackoverflow and I haven't been able to find a answer to my question, so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to create a dashboard which uses the Trello API in order to display specific metrics. The code section where I'm having trouble is here:

```
from django.conf import settings
from dashing.widgets import NumberWidget
from trello import TrelloApi

trello = TrelloApi(settings.API_KEY)

class TrelloCards(NumberWidget):
    title = 'The Difference Dashboard'
    def get_more_info(self):
        return ' {} closed'.format(len(trello.boards.get_card_filter('closed', 'BOARD_ID')))
    def get_change_rate(self):
        return ' {} open'.format(len(trello.boards.get_card_filter('closed', 'BOARD_ID')))
    def get_value(self):
        return len(trello.boards.get_card_filter('all', 'BOARD_ID'))
```

Where API_KEY is my Trello Developer API KEY and BOARD_ID is the id of the board I'm currently using.

When I go to run this code, I get an error message saying:

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/
'Settings' object has no attribute 'API_KEY'
```

I've tried changing the code to say

```
trello = TrelloApi(API_KEY)
```

In line with what the docs say, but this does not fix the issue.

If someone could just point me in the right direction with what I'm doing wrong, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Do you have something called `API_KEY` in your `settings.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put these three credentials into settings.py file of your projects:

**Settings.py**

```
TRELLO_API_KEY = 'your_trello_key'
TRELLO_API_SECRET = 'your_trello_api_secret'
CALLBACK_DOMAIN = 'your_trello_callback_domain'
```

Like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    .....
    .....
  ]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    .....
    .....
)

API_KEY = 'your_trello_api_key'
TRELLO_API_SECRET = 'your_trello_api_secret'
CALLBACK_DOMAIN = 'your_trello_callback_domain'
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm not sure where my Trello_API_SECRET and CALLBACK_DOMAIN can be found.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thanks for you help!

Comment: @stntmnky Your welcome.If it helped then you should accept the answer.